# How to achive painting like effect

Tags: effect

In some photographs we can see a [painting like effect](http://www.flickr.com/photos/celta4/9784102173/) . Can you tell me wheter this kind of effect is created after taking the photo (using some software) or changing shutter speed, iso or aperture of the camera.

Comment: Hi Eka! Could you please read [this post on about this type of question](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/psa-on-whats-this-effect-questions) and update your description a little bit? What you see as "painting like" isn't what I expected at all.

Comment: @mattdm As you mentioned in your post its hard to explain this "effect" in words. What i see in this photo is a coffee shop painted in oil medium. Depending upon others perception it may vary.

Comment: Could you _try_, though? It doesn't look like a painting to me, and if you could explain why you think it does, that might help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The photo in your link show an HDR post-processing.
This is done by software in post-processing like

```
  Photoshop
  Oleoneo
  Photomatrix
  HDR Efex Pro
```